# Javascript: Drag'n'drop starts with not-allowed cursor at the droptarget place: instantly not-allowed cursor flickers at the start of dragging

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, cursor

Drag'n'drop starts with not-allowed cursor at the droptarget place: instantly not-allowed cursor flickers at the start of dragging.

Please try this code and try dragging the white div:

```js
const target = document.getElementById("droptarget")
target.addEventListener("dragover", (event) => {
  event.preventDefault()
})
target.addEventListener("dragenter", (event) => {
  event.preventDefault()
})
```

```css
#draggable {
  text-align: center;
  background: white;
  height: 100px;
}

#droptarget {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blueviolet;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="droptarget">
  <div id="draggable" draggable="true">This div is draggable</div>
</div>
```

The not-allowed cursor should not be displayed, but it is displayed.

Here is my video: https://imgur.com/IKG2Lfz
And cursor: https://imgur.com/a/rP1T8Os

Comment: Windows 10, Chrome 120.0.6099.71
Try to drag very slowly... And there will be flickering when the cursor changes.

Comment: Here is my video:
https://imgur.com/IKG2Lfz

Comment: Drag works.
But the problem is not with the drag itself.
The problem is - instantly not-allowed cursor flickers at the start of dragging!!!
I don't know why you don't see the not-allowed cursor... Here: https://imgur.com/a/rP1T8Os

Comment: This is really strange. I always have this (like in the video). In the code snippet too.

Comment: I normally use a Mac, but I just used a Windows 10 machine, and I can confirm it does flicker and show the no-drop symbol. It was very fast, but I was able to record the screen and slow it down.

Comment: I don't think you're doing anything wrong. I also noticed that Chrome on Mac doesn't show the no-drop symbol at all when you drag outside of the drop target (like it does in Windows). I think the flicker could be a bug in Chrome.

Comment: I tested this drag in different browsers in windows: Chrome (Edge), Firefox - they all show the same not-allowed cursor behavior...
So the problem is not in Chrome.